# String search in mysqltable using python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to search the matching strings from a mysql table. The search string is not a correct sentence, its only a part of the sentence.Any one can help me.?

Thanks in advance...

Nimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE string LIKE '%substring%'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html